# How to combine multiple tables value into array of particular structure?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have these 2 (two) tables in mysql which are **users** and **details**:

**1. users**

```
  user_id   | login         | email 
 ---------- | ------------- | ------------ 
  1         | PSS1          | email1@email.com
  2         | PSS2          | email2@email.com
```

**2. details**

```
  id        | login         | datefrom     | dateto
 ---------- | ------------- | ------------   ------------
  1         | PSS1          | 2017-12-12   | 2017-12-13
  2         | PSS1          | 2017-12-15   | 2017-12-17
  3         | PSS2          | 2017-12-01   | 2017-12-02
```

And I have these PHP code to encode JSON output

**3. getjson.php**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");
    global $connect;

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $login = $_POST['login'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                $login_db    = $row['login'];
                $email_db    = $row['email'];

                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE login='$login'";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);
                if($result2 && mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

                        $dtfromdb = $row2['dtfrom'];
                        $dttodb   = $row2['dtto'];

                        $output = array(
                            'login'     => $login_db,     
                            'email'     => $email_db,
                            'movement'  => array(['dtfrom' => $dtfromdb,'dtto'  => $dttodb])
                        );
                        echo json_encode($output);
                    }
                }
                else {}
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else { echo 'not found'; }
    }
?>
```

My goal is to achieve the output something like below (4) where when the input is **equal to PSS1 in users table**, two records of **dtfrom** and **dtto** in details table display in "movement" array

**4. My goal of JSON output**

```
{
    "login":"PSS1",
    "email":"email1@email.com",
    "movement":
        [
            {
                "dtfrom":"2017-02-12",
                "dtto":"2017-02-13"
            },
            {

                "dtfrom":"2017-02-15",
                "dtto":"2017-02-17"
            }
        ]
}
```

The problem is, I can only managed to display single value (5) in details table as below

**5. current JSON ouput**

```
{
    "login":"PSS1",
    "email":"email1@email.com",
    "movement":
        [
            {
                "dtfrom":"2017-02-15",
                "dtto":"2017-02-17"
            }
        ]
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help me with this issue. Thanks

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes. I will take noted on that issue. But how to solve my question above ?

Comment: One way to make this easier on yourself is to use a `JOIN` and have one result-set to iterate over: `SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN details ON users.login=details.login`. Then group together those rows according to `users.login` as you iterate, accumulating into an array for each JSON record.

Comment: can you update PHP code above in your answer ? I'm not really understand how to use JOIN

Comment: Try it out and see what results you get. I think the solution will be more obvious at that point. It avoids double-iteration which can be a lot easier to handle.

Comment: I can give you a idea but not code ? will you do it ?

Comment: yes please. @krishnpatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think about the structure of the array, there are three levels. So assuming you only ever get one result from the **users** table:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");
global $connect;

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $login_db    = $row['login'];
            $email_db    = $row['email'];

            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE login='$login'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

            $movements = array();

            if($result2 && mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

                    $dtfromdb = $row2['dtfrom'];
                    $dttodb   = $row2['dtto'];

                    $movements[] = array('dtfrom' => $dtfromdb, 'dtto' => $dttodb);

                }
            }
            else {}

            $output = array('login' => $login_db, 'email' => $email_db, 'movements' => $movements));

        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
    else { echo 'not found'; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It work like a charm . . god bless you . . . :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create the desired structure in your SQL query as mentioned by @tadman. Also, you should take the advice to avoid SQL injection as mentioned by @tadman.
That said, and to keep the example simple, try this:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");
    global $connect;

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $rslt_ary = array();
        $sql = "SELECT users.login, user.email, details.datefrom, details.dateto
            FROM users 
            JOIN details
            ON details.login = users.login
            WHERE login='$login'
            ORDER BY users.login, details.datefrom;";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $curr_user = "";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                if($curr_user != $row['login']) {
                    $rslt_ary = array('login' => $row['login'], 'email' => $row['email'], 'movement' => array());
                    $curr_user = $result['login'];
                }
                $rslt_ary['movement'] = array('dtfrom' => $row['datefrom'],'dtto' => $row['dateto']);
            }
        } else { 
            echo 'not found'; 
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    $json_result = json_encode($rslt);
?>
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion. I keep noted on that . :)

Comment: Whoever did the down-vote, please at least say why so I can learn.